# Unable to read files using s3fs when uploaded via management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

Struggling with an issue using s3fs on an amazon linux ec2 instance backing onto an s3 bucket.  Got the FTP server configured and up and running.  Able to access files that I've uploaded as the same user.  When i try and access files that have been uploaded directly through the management console I'm unable to read them.

Can see them listed in the FTP client but unable to access those that have been uploaded through the console.

I've mounted the s3 bucket using the following command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/s3fs mybucketname \
-o use_cache=/tmp,iam_role="FTPs3role",allow_other /home/ftpuser1/ftp/files \
-o url="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```

The files that have been uploaded via the console have permissions as 640, uploaded directly have permissions of 777.

Tried to change the permisions of the users folder (containing the link to the s3 bucket inside it) but get an input output error.

Any ideas of how can read the files uploaded via the console as unable to access them?

Running s3fs v1.85 on Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by adding, -o complement_stat:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/s3fs mybucketname \
-o use_cache=/tmp,iam_role="FTPs3role",allow_other /home/ftpuser1/ftp/files \
-o complement_stat -o url="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```

It's related to the headers when uploaded via management console.  Used the above to map the folder and worked as expected.

Comment: this didn't quite work as expected in the end and had to add to the command: -o umask 0022